# Visual Studio 'Preview' tab builds entire solution

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, preview

When Previewing an SSRS report in Visual Studio 2017, every .rdl in the solution is built the first time. After that every .rdl is checked to see if it is 'Up-to-Date'.  We have some very large solutions and I am wondering if there is a way to stop the 'Preview' from looking at every report every time?

Comment: I think this just checks the .rdl date/time vs the version in the bin folder. If they are the same then it shoud skip them, it certainly does for me. If you clean the project then that might force a rebuild or if updates are coming from source control.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, it does 'Skip' after the initial build.  We were hoping to avoid the 'Skipping' as well.